# putting my password in php files (phpmailer)

Tags: php, passwords

I'm using phpmailer and to use it you have to set $mail->password

I worry that my password is going to be accessible by hackers. Do I need to do something to protect it? I could put the password in the class file which is in a certain directory. Would that be secure? If I password protect that directory would the php script be able to access it?

Please excuse my ignorance on the subject!

Comment: There is also an [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.  I'm not positive your question is on-topic there, but they have lots of info on this kind of stuff.

Comment: When using PHPMailer I usually create an email which is both not my personal one and does not use my personal password or any variation thereof. So websitemail@example.com has a password of `SJDohy4nkldDSJFHW*IEhuiwerg`. Set it and forget it.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone with access & run  your code will be able to find your password in one way or another. However if you are only concerned about plain text storage, a good idea is to use a hashed value as a password. This is specifically useful if the hacker is automated robot or is not able to read all the code.

You will need to change your account password to lets say md5 of the string 'password' and then you can set

```
  $password = 'password'; //it would be smart to put this in a separate file , eg config file.

  $mail->password = md5($password);
```

Answer (score 0):

md5 didn't work for me (probably I didn't do it right), however following worked for me:

1) saved password in a separate 'filename.php' as

```
$password = 'mypassword';
```

2) entered at the top of my phpmailer file

```
require_once 'filename.php';
```

3) recalled password in phpmailer script as follows

```
$mail->Password = $password;
```

Hope it helps other fellow beginners!